# Python: Looping over list of countries for holidays

Tags: python, python-holidays

I am fairly new to Python. I am leveraging Python's [holiday](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/#modal-close) package which has public holidays by country. In order to get a country's holiday, you can run something like:

`sorted(holidays.US(years=np.arange(2014,2030,1)).items()`

This will give the date and holiday. Now, I want the data against a bunch of countries. How do I loop over the list of countries instead of replacing the country name in the above code every single time?
the countries under consideration here are:

`[FRA, Norway, Finland, US, Germany, UnitedKingdom, Sweden]`

I tried a for loop like this:

```
countrylistLoop = ['FRA', 'Norway', 'Finland', 'US', 'Germany', 'UnitedKingdom', 'Sweden']

for i in countrylistLoop:
     print(sorted(holidays.i(years=np.arange(2014,2030,1)).items()),columns=['Date','Holiday'])
```

This throws an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: module 'holidays' has no attribute 'i'.
```

This makes sense but I am not sure how to proceed!

Ideally, I would like to loop over and store the results in a dataframe. Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the items the following way

```py
import holidays
countrylistLoop = ['FRA', 'Norway', 'Finland', 'US', 'Germany', 'UnitedKingdom', 'Sweden']
for country in countrylistLoop:
    hd = sorted(holidays.CountryHoliday(country, years=np.arange(2014,2030,1)).items())
```

But it doesn't take the `columns` argument for sorted.

or you can sort items based on the index

```py
hd = sorted(list(holidays.CountryHoliday(country, 
            years=np.arange(2014,2030,1)).items()), 
            key=lambda holiday: holiday[1])
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks a lot! How could I add the country identifier to the list? Adding an `i` throws an error.

Comment: are you suing `holidays.CountryHoliday` ?

Comment: Yes. I am using the code you provided. I just need an additional country identifier there.

Answer (score 1):

To provide an additional country identifier you can do this:

```
all_holidays = []
country_list = ['UnitedStates', 'India', 'Germany']

for country in country_list:
    for holiday in holidays.CountryHoliday(country, years = np.arange(2018,2021,1)).items():
        all_holidays.append({'date' : holiday[0], 'holiday' : holiday[1], 'country': country})
all_holidays = pd.DataFrame(all_holidays)
all_holidays
```

The result will be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHC0g.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in countrylistLoop:
    holiday = getattr(holidays, i)(years=np.arange(2014,2030,1)).items()
    sorted(holiday)
    print(holiday)
```

To get an attribute dynamically, use `getattr`.

Otherwise, I split the `sorted` function out because it returns `None`, as all mutating builtins for python do.